# Evaluate a value in a switch block using comparisons in each case

Tags: php, switch-statement, conditional-statements

Suppose I have a variable integer and wish to do different things if the value is greater then one value and less then another value. My objective for this switch, is basically to send different results based on the value of `$chance`, which I will have many cases in the end as this is for a game.

```
switch ($chance)
{
    case ($chance < 15):
        echo"strike<br>";
    case ($chance < 15 && $chance > 50):
        echo"Ball<br>";
        break;
    case ($chance < 50 && $chance > 100):
        echo"Single<br>";
        break;
    case ($chance <= 150 && $chance >= 100):
        echo"double<br>";
        break;
    case ($chance <= 175 && $chance >= 151):
        echo"triple<br>";
        break;
    case ($chance > 200 && $chance > 175):
        echo"Ground Rule Double<br>";
        break;
    case ($chance < 200):
        echo"Home Run<br>";
        break;
}
```

Now, I've been told that I can use conditionals in switch statements, and I've also been told that I should not use them. I really don't know who to believe.

What I do know, is that currently, this switch statement does not work as intended. It doesn't generate syntax errors, but I will get random echos back. This happens when sometimes the chance may be 100 and I will get a home run echo. I'm not sure.

I know I could do the same with a series of `if` but it would amount to a huge difference in length of code if I can achieve the same results.

I imagine I can do something like

```
case 1:
 echo this
case 2:
 echo that
etc etc
```

Until I hit 2 or 300 but I would like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: And what would you expect? `case ($chance < 15 && $chance > 50):` a variable can't have both those values at the same time!!!

Comment: Do not try to get too cute with what you are doing based on "length of code".  No points are awarded for writing unclear, convoluted code that is shorter than clear, easily understandable code.  I don't see if the if-else would result in more code anyway. If anything it is shorter because you don't need the break statements.

Comment: Also, note that you are missing a break after echo"strike<br>"; is this deliberate?

Comment: i guess length of code wasn not nessacarily what i meant it was more so about the length of time it would take the script to process 100 if/else vs 100 cases in a switch i had not used switch previously and have been testing it out and apparantly i crisscrossed some greater than/ less operators in this iteration and jtheman wants everyone to know that,

Comment: Length of time. Should be non-noticeable for your use case. Also, switches help because they evaluate the case statement once. but that's not relevant here as its a simple type.

Answer (score 2):

This is not how you use the switch statement. This is an example of a correct way:

```
switch ($a) {
  case 1:
    echo 1;
    break;
  case 2:
    echo 2; 
    break;
  default:
    echo 0;
}
```

For what you want to accomplish you need to use the old `if-else` statements.

```
if ($chance < 15)
    echo"strike<br>";
else if ($chance >= 15 && $chance < 50)
    echo"Ball<br>";
else if ($chance >= 50 && $chance < 100)
    echo"Single<br>";
else if ($chance <= 150 && $chance >= 100)
    echo"double<br>";
else if ($chance <= 175 && $chance >= 151)
    echo"triple<br>";
else if ($chance < 200 && $chance > 175)
    echo"Ground Rule Double<br>";
else if ($chance <= 200)
    echo"Home Run<br>";
```

Comment: But `if ($chance < 15 && $chance > 50):` - get that?

Comment: thanks buddy, i originally had a series of if /else if but was testing out how much better switch would work in wake of if/else, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Switch statement syntax:

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

```
<?php
switch ($i) {
    case 0:
        echo "i equals 0";
        break;
    case 1:
        echo "i equals 1";
        break;
    case 2:
        echo "i equals 2";
        break;
    default:
       echo "i is not equal to 0, 1 or 2";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do what you are wanting to do, you should use an if-else.  The value used for the case expression must be an integer, floating-point decimal, or string.

Comment: Have you tried? A conditional that evaluates to a boolean (as in the op) works just fine.

Comment: The OP's code works as expected. Their logic is just flawed which results in it not working correctly.

Comment: @Crisp It won't work when you are trying to evaluate multiple ranges of values like this. In this case yo would have 7 cases statements that evaluate to either true or false.  What sense does it make to have 7 options when there is a cardinality of only 2? You are also not saving anything performance wise, as you are still doing the same number of evaluations as you would in if-else, so this is just a convoluted way of doing things.

Comment: @MikeBrant the OP's dubious maths aside, my point was that expressions can be used in case statements, not just integers, floating point decimals or strings, which is what your answer claims.

Comment: upon further review and a little fixing of my math i have the switch statement working perfect with these same conditionals

Answer (score 0):

You need just set **true** in you `switch`. Use `switch (true)` **instead** of `switch ($chance)`.

now your code will be:

```
switch (true)
{
    case ($chance < 15):
        echo"strike<br>";
    case ($chance < 15 && $chance > 50):
        echo"Ball<br>";
        break;
    case ($chance < 50 && $chance > 100):
        echo"Single<br>";
        break;
    case ($chance <= 150 && $chance >= 100):
        echo"double<br>";
        break;
    case ($chance <= 175 && $chance >= 151):
        echo"triple<br>";
        break;
    case ($chance > 200 && $chance > 175):
        echo"Ground Rule Double<br>";
        break;
    case ($chance < 200):
        echo"Home Run<br>";
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite some mathematical/comparison issues in your code, it seems that you intend to set numeric ranges that correspond to specific outcomes.   It also seems inappropriate to reach multiple outcomes in a single script execution.

Given these truths, you should use an `if-elseif-else` block.  It will be more appropriate and less verbose than a `switch` block.

The ONLY advantage to using a switch block is when you need to make 1 evaluation and take different actions based on that evaluation.  Because you are making multiple evaluations, there is no advantage in using a switch -- in fact, the computational complexity will be the same and the syntax will either be of equal or greater length versus an if block.  I personally have such a distaste for switch blocks that I endeavor to use any other viable technique instead.  Switch blocks only make very rare appearances in my professional projects.

By progressing in an ASC or DESC fashion, you will only need one expression in each condition.  Using consistent operators in each condition will make your script easier to maintain/extend.

Finally, in PHP, `elseif` is one word not two.

Code:

```
if ($chance < 0) {
    $result = 'Balk';     // ;)
} elseif ($chance < 15) {
    $result = 'Strike';
} elseif ($chance < 50) {
    $result = 'Ball';
} elseif ($chance < 100) {
    $result = 'Single';
} elseif ($chance < 150) {
    $result = 'Double';
} elseif ($chance < 175) {
    $result = 'Triple';
} elseif ($chance < 200) {
    $result = 'Ground Rule Double';
} else {
    $result = 'Home Run';
}
echo "$result<br>";
```